# How to make a CSS Menu "Selected" with Hover Image Gallery Effect?

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to make the first navigation menu option a "**selected**" class that displays the image on the right automatically (by default) when you get to the web page.

Then when you hover your mouse over the other links it still displays the other images properly. Right now, you don't see the first image until you move your mouse over **"shirts"** on the menu.

Link: http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/readymade.html

Any CSS tips or suggestions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can be closed based on this close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that would preserve your current structure would be to make the images visible when the links have focus.

### [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3734782)

The HTML structure stays almost the same, I've only added `tabindex=1` to the links

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li class="thumb">
        <a class="thumb" href="#" tabindex=1>Orion</a>
        <div><img src="http://i.space.com/images/i/20521/i02/eso-orion-nebula-1600.jpg" alt="blue shirt" border="0"><br><a class="selected" href="images/blueshirt.jpg" border="0"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <a class="thumb" href="#" tabindex=1>Pencil</a>
        <div><img src="http://i.space.com/images/i/21535/i02/pencil-nebula-wide-1600.jpg" alt=""><br><a class="enlarge" href="images/P1010426.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <a class="thumb" href="#" tabindex=1>Carina</a>
        <div><img src="http://i.space.com/images/i/15222/i02/carina-nebula-1600-1200.jpg" alt=""><br><a class="enlarge" href="images/P1010426.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <a class="thumb" href="#" tabindex=1>Trifid</a>
        <div><img src="http://i.space.com/images/i/19657/i02/trifid-nebula-1600.jpg" alt=""><br><a class="enlarge" href="images/P1010426.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS I've used - kept it minimal to outline the functionality (and also because I'm falling asleep), you can add eye candy:

```
div { position: absolute; left: 0; opacity: 0; transition: 1s; }
a:focus { outline: none; }
li:first-child div, a:focus + div, a:active + div { opacity: 1; }
```

I've stacked the divs ontaing the images to be on top of the other and used `opacity: 0;` to hide them. I've then set the first one to have `opacity: 1` and the same for the one corresponding to the link that has focus (also used the `a:active` for IE).

The main disadvantage of this method is that it is not persistent. Once you click anywhere else on the page, the link last clicked loses focus and the opacity of the corresponding div which holds the image becomes 0 again.

---

In order to make it persistent, you would have to alter the HTML a bit more, using something that's called the checkbox hack. That involves replacing the links with radio inputs corresponding labels, hiding the radio buttons and bringing the opacity to 1 when the corresponding radio button is checked (`input[type=radio]:checked`).

### [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3734840)

HTML became:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li class="thumb">
        <input type=radio name=i id=i1 checked>
        <label for=i1>Orion</label>
        <div><img src="http://i.space.com/images/i/20521/i02/eso-orion-nebula-1600.jpg" alt="blue shirt" border="0"><br><a class="selected" href="images/blueshirt.jpg" border="0"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <input type=radio name=i id=i2>
        <label for=i2>Pencil</label>
        <div><img src="http://i.space.com/images/i/21535/i02/pencil-nebula-wide-1600.jpg" alt=""><br><a class="enlarge" href="images/P1010426.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <input type=radio name=i id=i3>
        <label for=i3>Carina</label>
        <div><img src="http://i.space.com/images/i/15222/i02/carina-nebula-1600-1200.jpg" alt=""><br><a class="enlarge" href="images/P1010426.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <input type=radio name=i id=i4>
        <label for=i4>Trifid</label>
        <div><img src="http://i.space.com/images/i/19657/i02/trifid-nebula-1600.jpg" alt=""><br><a class="enlarge" href="images/P1010426.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
input[type=radio] { display: none; }
label { cursor: pointer; }
div { position: absolute; left: 0; opacity: 0; transition: 1s; }
input[type=radio]:checked ~ div { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: Wow Ana you're amazing! I never thought about that! That make sense to have the image displaying already lol!

Thank you so much!